# RHAOS packages on RHEL

Tags: rhel, rpm, redhat-satellite, openshift

I am downloading some RPM packages from the Red Hat Customer site and came across some `rhaos` packages. I'm not sure what they are exactly.

For example: `podman-4.4.1-3.rhaos4.13.el8.x86_64.rpm`

I couldn't find much information about them, except that they are related to OpenShift.
Can these packages be safely installed on RHEL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RHAOS refers to Red Hat Atomic OpenShift. Those packages are specifically designed for use on OpenShift nodes. While they may work on regular RHEL nodes, it is recommended to use regular RHEL packages (or module packages) for better compatibility.

You can find out what product a package is associated with by looking at the package details; this shows for example that the latest RHEL non-beta Podman package is [4.4.1-14.module+el8.8.0+19108+ffbdcd02](https://access.redhat.com/downloads/content/podman/4.4.1-14.module+el8.8.0+19108+ffbdcd02/x86_64/fd431d51/package).